# Not able to clear "SOCKS" in Eclipse network connections

Tags: eclipse

I am not able to download using the eclipse update software. I have been getting "HTTP PROXY AUTHENTICATION ERROR". Understood by searching in StackOverflow that this requires the "SOCKS" option to be disabled as it tryies to connect using SOCKS instead of  HTTP/HTTPS proxy details i have provided. But when i try disabling the checkbox or rather clear it i am not able to clear "SOCKS" entry. I thought it must be a bug in eclipse and changed the version but still seeing the same issue. The eclipse platform version I have is: 4.4.2.v20150204-1700

Appreciate any help on resolving this issue

[image]

Comment: I still have this problem with Eclipse neon.3

Comment: Have you tried changing `Active provider` type from the dropdown above to `Direct` or `Native` ?